Error: "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation" with Get-PnPFile in SharePoint Online
I'm encountering an issue with the Get-PnPFile cmdlet in SharePoint Online PowerShell. Despite being the site collection owner and having list permissions enabled, I consistently receive the following error:
Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
I have recently switched to PowerShell 7.4.2 & PnP.Powershell 2.4.0 , also I've double-checked my permissions and ensured that list permissions are there, but the error persists. Could anyone provide insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TargetSiteURL -UseWebLogin -ForceAuthentication 

$TargetCtx = Get-PnPContext

$targetConnection = Get-PnPConnection

# Get target list
$TargetList = Get-PnPList -Identity $TargetListName -Connection $targetConnection
# Get target items
$TargetItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $TargetList -Connection $targetConnection
$Attachments = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $SourceItem -Property "AttachmentFiles" -Connection $SourceConnection
if ($Attachments) {
    $Attachments | ForEach-Object {
        # Download the attachment to Temp
        $File = Get-PnPFile -Url $_.ServerRelativeUrl -FileName $_.FileName -Path $env:TEMP -AsFile -Force -Connection $SourceConnection

        # Add attachment to target list item
        $FileStream = New-Object IO.FileStream(($env:TEMP + "\" + $_.FileName), [System.IO.FileMode]::Open) 
        $AttachmentInfo = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AttachmentCreationInformation
        $AttachmentInfo.FileName = $_.FileName
        $AttachmentInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream
        $AttachFile = $TargetItem.AttachmentFiles.Add($AttachmentInfo)
        $TargetItem.Context.ExecuteQuery()   

        # Delete the temporary file
        Remove-Item -Path $env:TEMP\$($_.FileName) -Force
    }
} ```


We are making use of -UseWebLogin for Connect-PnpOnline as we cannot do Powershell registration at the moment because of some reason and thus relying on -UseWebLogin which bypass the registration in azure.

